# URL rewrite to a different virtual directory without changing URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I have a multi tenant web application that uses one virtual directory in IIS.

Example:
foo.example.com/100
boo.example.com/100

I want one of my clients to view some new features but dont want to change the URL. I created another virtual directory called preview. How do I configure URL rewrite to point foo.example.com/100 to the new virtual directory "preview" without changing the URL (foo.example.com/100)? Thanks!

```
    <rule name="Preview URL Rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="100/(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^foo.example.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="preview/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: You'd better show your URL rewrite rules.

Comment: @LexLi I apologize. See updated post. Thanks.